# Python: I'm trying to import an instance from module 2 and run it through a class in module 1

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I have tried several "solutions" on this site and other and I must be missing something. Why does the code pictured give a name error.

I've tried from cars2 import * but that didn't work as well as a few others.

I'm out of ideas. What am I missing?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHuay.jpg

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. No one likes to look at screenshots to find errors in code.

Comment: I'm sure someone does. No one is a pretty bold absolute to make.  Also it's the only access to this code that I have as my computer doesn't have working internet at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the class `cars` before defining it.

You should do the following:

In the file `cars1.py`:

```
class cars:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
```

In the file `cars2.py`:

```
from cars1 import cars
firstCar = cars("Honda")

print(firstCar.model)
```

And while running the code, you should run `cars2.py` and not `cars1.py`.

So you should run it as `python cars2.py` if you are using command line from the folder in which the file `cars2.py` file is saved in.

You can also do run the code `cars1.py` by updating it as follows:

```
class cars:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

if __name__=="__main__":
    from cars2 import firstCar
    print(firstCar.model)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was hoping to leave one file for just the different instances though, so that they could be called into multiple modules. Is this just not possible with python?

Comment: It can be done. You can make the instances in a file. And then call all those instances from say file `cars3.py`. It will throw an error if you call the instance from file `cars1.py` directly unless you define it under the `if __name__=="__main__":` block in `cars1.py`.